# Cant read JSON data from URL with Android

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to read JSON data form a URL, and currently i got this code snippet inside my onCreate method in my MainActivity class:

```
try {
        URL url = new URL("https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/rest/bug/35");

        try{

            InputStream in = url.openStream();

            JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

            // more will be there...

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When I run the app on a virtual device, it says that the program is stopped, it can't even start it.
Maybe I'm trying to read the data in a wrong way.
The most important thing, is that I want to read JSON data from URL. I also added the INTERNET permission to the aplication, but it didn't help.

Comment: stacktrace. read it.

Comment: Are you running this on the UI thread?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to perform network operation and For connecting to url use [UrlConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html).
for example see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29465996/how-to-get-json-object-using-httpurlconnection-instead-of-volley)

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what i wanted to get :)