# JSONParser from androidhive tutorial, NoSuchMethodError in DefaultHttpClient

Tags: java, android

I'm following [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) tutorial, and getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method execute(Lorg/apache/http/client/methods/HttpUriRequest;)Lorg/apache/http/client/methods/CloseableHttpResponse; in class Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient' appears in /system/framework/ext.jar)
                at info.androidhive.materialtabs.adpater.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:52)
                at info.androidhive.materialtabs.UserFunctions.loginUser(UserFunctions.java:37)
                at info.androidhive.materialtabs.activity.MainActivity$Login.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:551)
                at info.androidhive.materialtabs.activity.MainActivity$Login.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:519)
```

Here is the JSONParser class that I'm using:

```
public class JSONParser {
     static InputStream is = null;
        static JSONObject jObj = null;
        static String json = "";
        // constructor
        public JSONParser() {
        }
        // function get json from url
        // by making HTTP POST or GET method
        public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                List<NameValuePair> params) {
            // Making HTTP request
            try {
                // check for request method
                if(method == "POST"){
                    // request method is POST
                    // defaultHttpClient
                    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                    is = httpEntity.getContent();
                }else if(method == "GET"){
                    // request method is GET
                    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                    url += "?" + paramString;
                    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                    is = httpEntity.getContent();
                }           
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                json = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }
            // try parse the string to a JSON object
            try {
                jObj = new JSONObject(json);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }
            // return JSON String
            return jObj;
        }
}
```

Comment: which part of code is responsible  for this error log, u can post that also

Comment: using json parse like this :

Comment: Post your code and explain your problem little bit clearly

Comment: HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    is = httpEntity.getContent();

Comment: HttpPost is deprecated one try to use HttpUrlConnection or Gson

Comment: Can u please edit and send it to me because i am not getting it

Answer (score 10):

DefaultHttpClient was deprecated in api level 22, and removed in api level 23.

The documentation was even removed from the Android documentation, here is the link to where the documentation was previously, and you can see where it re-directs to:
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html

Quote just in case the re-direct changes:

> Android 6.0 release removes support for the Apache HTTP client. If
>   your app is using this client and targets Android 2.3 (API level 9) or
>   higher, use the HttpURLConnection class instead. This API is more
>   efficient because it reduces network use through transparent
>   compression and response caching, and minimizes power consumption.

I created an updated version of the JSONParser class that you're using, here it is:

```
import android.util.Log;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class JSONParser {

    String charset = "UTF-8";
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    DataOutputStream wr;
    StringBuilder result;
    URL urlObj;
    JSONObject jObj = null;
    StringBuilder sbParams;
    String paramsString;

    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                      HashMap<String, String> params) {

        sbParams = new StringBuilder();
        int i = 0;
        for (String key : params.keySet()) {
            try {
                if (i != 0){
                    sbParams.append("&");
                }
                sbParams.append(key).append("=")
                        .append(URLEncoder.encode(params.get(key), charset));

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            i++;
        }

        if (method.equals("POST")) {
            // request method is POST
            try {
                urlObj = new URL(url);

                conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();

                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);

                conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);

                conn.connect();

                paramsString = sbParams.toString();

                wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                wr.writeBytes(paramsString);
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else if(method.equals("GET")){
            // request method is GET

            if (sbParams.length() != 0) {
                url += "?" + sbParams.toString();
            }

            try {
                urlObj = new URL(url);

                conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();

                conn.setDoOutput(false);

                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);

                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);

                conn.connect();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        try {
            //Receive the response from the server
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            result = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }

            Log.d("JSON Parser", "result: " + result.toString());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        conn.disconnect();

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(result.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON Object
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

Example AsyncTask for Post:

```
class PostAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://www.example.com/testPost.php";

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

        try {

            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("name", args[0]);
            params.put("password", args[1]);

            Log.d("request", "starting");

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

            if (json != null) {
                Log.d("JSON result", json.toString());

                return json;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

        int success = 0;
        String message = "";

        if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

        if (json != null) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, json.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            try {
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                message = json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (success == 1) {
            Log.d("Success!", message);
        }else{
            Log.d("Failure", message);
        }
    }

}
```

Example AsyncTask for Get:

```
class GetAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://www.example.com/testGet.php";

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

        try {

            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("name", args[0]);
            params.put("password", args[1]);

            Log.d("request", "starting");

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    LOGIN_URL, "GET", params);

            if (json != null) {
                Log.d("JSON result", json.toString());

                return json;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

        int success = 0;
        String message = "";

        if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

        if (json != null) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, json.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            try {
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                message = json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (success == 1) {
            Log.d("Success!", message);
        }else{
            Log.d("Failure", message);
        }
    }

}
```

For more details, here's my blog post about this code:  http://danielnugent.blogspot.com/2015/06/updated-jsonparser-with.html

Comment: Error:(74, 37) error: method makeHttpRequest in class JSONParser cannot be applied to given types;
required: String,String,HashMap<String,String>
found: String,String,List<NameValuePair>
reason: actual argument List<NameValuePair> cannot be converted to HashMap<String,String> by method invocation conversion

Comment: @chawla.19 NameValuePair was also deprecated in api level 22, and removed in api level 23.  Take a look at the example AsyncTasks, you'll need to put your parameters into a HashMap instead of using NameValuePair.

Comment: Error:(38, 27) error: cannot find symbol method keySet()

Comment: @chawla.19 keySet() is a standard method in the HashMap class.  Did you replace the full code in your JSONParser class, including the imports?

Comment: @chawla.19 not sure why you're getting a compile error there.  Just so you know, this code is fully working and tested.  I did comprehensive testing before I posted it on my blog.  Once you get it compiling correctly I'm sure it will work for you.

Comment: its showing : wrong 3rd argument type. Found:'java.util.ArrayList<org.apache.http.NameValuePair>',required:'java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>'

Comment: @chawla.19 You need to construct a HashMap with your parameters instead of using NameValuePairs, and give that as the third parameter for the `makeHttpRequest()` method.  Take a look at the example AsyncTasks in the answer!

Comment: when i construct a 'HashMap' , it gives keySet error as mentioned above

Comment: @chawla.19 If you correctly create a HashMap it should not give any errors.  Again, this is fully working and tested code.  Keep at it and you'll get it!

Comment: saved my day as I am also getting error at execute method after i updated API 24, now ok, many many thanks!