# AsyncTask error while execution of a json parsing in doInBackground

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask, httprequest

Attached you can find my code:

```
public class Login extends Activity {

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}

private final float L_LEVEL=0.75f;
private final float M_LEVEL=1.0f;
private final float H_LEVEL=1.5f;
private final float X_LEVEL=2.0f;

private EditText Username;
private EditText Password;
private Form mForm;
private Button btnLogin;
private Button btnRegister;

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();


private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://10.0.2.2/obat/login.php";
private static final String GET_USERNAME = "http://10.0.2.2/obat/server.php?operasi=op2";
private static final String URL_ATURAN= "http://10.0.2.2/obat/server.php?operasi=op24";

private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

UserGlobals data_user = UserGlobals.getInstance();
public Builder builder;
public int status = 2;
public View view1;
public String phone;
public String username; 
public String password;
public TextView tvphone;
protected View view3;
private View view2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = 
                new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
    float level = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    if(level == L_LEVEL){

    //do something here
        int x = 120;

        DensityGlobals density = DensityGlobals.getInstance();
        density.setData(String.valueOf(x));

    } else if(level == M_LEVEL){

    //do smoothing here
        int x = 160;

        DensityGlobals density = DensityGlobals.getInstance();
        density.setData(String.valueOf(x));

    } else if(level == H_LEVEL){

    //do something here
        int x = 240;

        DensityGlobals density = DensityGlobals.getInstance();
        density.setData(String.valueOf(x));


    } else if(level == X_LEVEL){

    //do something here
        int x = 320;
        DensityGlobals density = DensityGlobals.getInstance();
        density.setData(String.valueOf(x));

    } else {
        int x = 320;
        DensityGlobals density = DensityGlobals.getInstance();
        density.setData(String.valueOf(x));
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    Username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txUser);
    Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txPass);
      username = Username.getText().toString();
      password = Password.getText().toString();

    initValidationForm();

     view1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.aktivasi, null);
        tvphone = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.phone);
     btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bLogin);
     btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            login();
            btnLogin.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });

     btnRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bRegister);
     btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, Register.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
}


    private void initValidationForm() {
        mForm = new Form(this);
        mForm.addField(Field.using(Username).validate(NotEmpty.build(this)));
        mForm.addField(Field.using(Password).validate(NotEmpty.build(this)));

    }

    private void login() {
        FormUtils.hideKeyboard(Login.this, Password);
        if (mForm.isValid()) {
         //   Crouton.makeText(this, getString(R.string.sample_activity_form_is_valid), Style.CONFIRM).show();
            //Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.sample_activity_form_is_valid), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();// get Internet status

            // check for Internet status
            if (isNetworkAvailable(Login.this)) {
                // Internet Connection is Present
                // make HTTP requests


                GetAturan();
                //showAlertDialog(Login.this, "Internet Connection","You have internet connection", true);
            } else {
                // Internet connection is not present
                // Ask user to connect to Internet
                showAlertDialog(Login.this, "No Internet Connection",
                        "You don't have internet connection.", false);
            }

        }
    }
    class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

         /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        boolean failure = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             // Check for success tag
            int success; 
            String con = "";

            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

                Log.d("request!", "starting");
                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                       LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

             // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    status = json.getInt("status");

                    if (success == 1) {
                     if (status == 1) {
                        Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());

                        data_user.setIds(json.getString("kd_pelanggan"));
                        data_user.setUsers(json.getString("username"));

                        data_user.setNama(json.getString("pelanggan"));
                        data_user.setProvinsi(json.getString("provinsi"));
                        data_user.setKota(json.getString("kota"));
                        data_user.setKodepos(json.getString("kodepos"));
                        data_user.setAlamat(json.getString("alamat"));
                        data_user.setEmail(json.getString("email"));
                        data_user.setBb(json.getString("bb"));
                        data_user.setTelp(json.getString("hp"));
                        //getUsername(username, password);

                        Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, Home.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
                         return null;
                     }

                }else {
                    Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;

        }
        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
             if(status == 0 ){

                builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this);
                 builder.setTitle("Aktivasi Akun")
                 .setCancelable(false);
                 builder.setPositiveButton("Call", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                           Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" +phone.toString()));
                            startActivity(callIntent);
                       }
                   })
                   .setNegativeButton("Nanti", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                           dialog.cancel();
                            btnLogin.setEnabled(true);
                       }
                   });
                 builder.setView(view1);
                 builder.create();
                 builder.show();
             } else if (status == 2) {
                 Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Your Internet Connections too low", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    btnLogin.setEnabled(true);
             }
                 pDialog.dismiss();
            if (file_url != null){
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }

    public void GetAturan(){
        JsonArrayRequest kategoriReq = new JsonArrayRequest(URL_ATURAN,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d("TAG", response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();

                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                phone = obj.getString("telp");
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                        System.out.println(phone.toString());

                         tvphone.setText(phone.toString());
                         new AttemptLogin().execute();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d("TAG", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                         view2 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_conection, null);
                        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this);
                         builder.setTitle("Attention")
                         .setCancelable(false);
                         builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                               @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                    btnLogin.setEnabled(true);
                                   dialog.dismiss();
                               }
                           });
                         builder.setView(view2);
                         builder.create();
                         builder.show();
                    }
                });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(kategoriReq);
    }
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
    return true;
}
/**
public void getUsername(String Username, String Password) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(GET_USERNAME +"&user="+Username+"&pass="+Password,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d("Get id", response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();
                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            data_user.setIds(obj.getString("kd_pelanggan"));
                            data_user.setUsers(obj.getString("username"));
                            data_user.setNama(obj.getString("nama"));
                            data_user.setProvinsi(obj.getString("provinsi"));
                            data_user.setKota(obj.getString("kota"));
                            data_user.setKodepos(obj.getString("kodepos"));
                            data_user.setAlamat(obj.getString("alamat"));
                            data_user.setEmail(obj.getString("mail"));
                            data_user.setBb(obj.getString("bb"));
                            data_user.setTelp(obj.getString("hp"));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, Home.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d("Get id", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hidePDialog();
                }
            });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
}
*/
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    hidePDialog();
}

private void hidePDialog() {
    if (pDialog != null) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        pDialog = null;
    }
}

public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
    return ((ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo() != null;
}
/**
 * Function to display simple Alert Dialog
 * @param context - application context
 * @param title - alert dialog title
 * @param message - alert message
 * @param status - success/failure (used to set icon)
 * */
public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message, Boolean status) {
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle(title);

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage(message);


    // Setting OK Button
    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

for logcat

**10-12 12:38:47.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1837): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
E/AndroidRuntime(1837): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()**

What's wrong in my code ???

Comment: did you debug it?. Instead of printing the stackTrace log the error, like Log.e(TAG, "error message: " + e.getMessage(), e);

Comment: Post your entire stack trace.  Regardless, it's probably connection issue and json is probably null when you call `json.toString()` in the Log statement.  Furthermore, you're probably using the JSONParser class that uses deprecated methods, given that you're using the deprecated NameValuePair List.  Take a look here for an updated version of JSONParser that I made: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33030660/jsonparser-from-androidhive-tutorial-nosuchmethoderror-in-defaulthttpclient/33031158#33031158

Comment: i change to api 22, and it's work thanks