# App crashes on HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

Tags: java, android, mysql

I working in `android studio`. I spent a lot of time searching how to retrive a specific row from mysql database but realy I cant do it every time my app crashed in `HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);`.

**here is JSONParser class**

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            int aa=sb.toString().indexOf("{");
            int zz=sb.indexOf("{",aa+1);
            String sss,zzz;
            sss=sb.substring(932);
            zzz=sb.substring(zz);
            //json = sb.toString();
            json=zzz.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
            /*JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(json);
            jObj=jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);*/

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

**and this is activity**

```
public class EditProductActivity extends Activity {

    EditText txtName;
    EditText txtPrice;
    EditText txtDesc;
    EditText txtCreatedAt;
    Button btnSave;
    Button btnDelete;

    String pid;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    // single product url
    private static final String url_product_detials = "http://10.20.40.105/android_connect/get_product_details.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCT = "product";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";
    private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.edit_product);


        // getting product details from intent
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // getting product id (pid) from intent
        pid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_PID);

        // Getting complete product details in background thread
        new GetProductDetails().execute();

        });



    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Get complete product details
     * */
    class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading product details. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Getting product details in background thread
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // Check for success tag
                    int success;
                    try {
                        // Building Parameters
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));
                        // getting product details by making HTTP request
                        // Note that product details url will use GET request
                        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                                url_product_detials, "GET", params);
                        // check your log for json response
                        Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                        // json success tag
                        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                        if (success == 1) {
                            // successfully received product details
                            JSONArray productObj = json
                                    .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); // JSON Array

                            // get first product object from JSON Array
                            JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                            // product with this pid found
                            // Edit Text
                            txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
                            txtPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
                            txtDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

                            // display product data in EditText
                            txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
                            txtPrice.setText(product.getString(TAG_PRICE));
                            txtDesc.setText(product.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));

                        }else{
                            // product with pid not found
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            return null;
        }


        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once got all details
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }    
}
```

**and in the last my php cod**

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will get single product details
 * A product is identified by product id (pid)
 */

// array for JSON response

$response = array();
$response["success"] = 0;

// include db connect class

require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db

$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// check for post data

if (isset($_GET["pid"])) {
    $pid = $_GET['pid'];

    // get a product from products table
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE pid like $pid");

    if (!empty($result)) {
        // check for empty result
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

            $product = array();
            $product["pid"] = $result["pid"];
            $product["name"] = $result["name"];
            $product["price"] = $result["price"];
            $product["description"] = $result["description"];
            $product["created_at"] = $result["created_at"];
            $product["updated_at"] = $result["updated_at"];
            // success
            $response["success"] = 1;

            // user node
            $response["product"] = array();

            array_push($response["product"], $product);

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // no product found
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "No product found";

            // echo no users JSON
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else {
        // no product found
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No product found";

        // echo no users JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: Add log output of the crash/stacktrace. If you are using api-23, this will help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33030660/jsonparser-from-androidhive-tutorial-nosuchmethoderror-in-defaulthttpclient

Comment: solve in the class of @DanielNugent thank you sooooo
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33030660/jsonparser-from-androidhive-tutorial-nosuchmethoderror-in-defaulthttpclient

Answer (score 0):

Declare internet permission in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> every time my app crashed in
>
> HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

Getting `NetworkOnMainThreadException`  because  `HttpResponse.execute` method is called on UI Thread using `runOnUiThread`  in `doInBackground`.

No need to use `runOnUiThread` when using `AsyncTask`  just return `json.toString()` from `doInBackground` :

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
 List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
 params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));
 
 JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                            url_product_detials, "GET", params);
  return json.toString();
}
```

and access UI from `onPostExecute`  method for updating UI :

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        JSONObject json =new JSONObject(result);  
        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
        if (success == 1) {
          // your code here...
        }
   }
```

Comment: when i delete runOnUithread i have   variable params is already defined in the scope

Comment: @Hamzahizam:  not clear what problem getting after removing `runOnUithread ` ?