# Alternative for deprecated HttpClient, HttpPost, NameValuePair

Tags: android, httpsurlconnection, basicnamevaluepair

I've been searching a lot, however haven't find any solution. I want to use `URL`, `HttpsUrlConnection` instead of deprecated ones (`HttpClient, HttpPost, DefaultHttpClient`). I have this code below so far:

**Note** "MyUrl" takes some parameters. See question 2.

```
 URL url = new URL("MyUrl");
    HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

    /*Here exception occurs!*/
    connection.connect();
```

So, I have 2 problems to solve: (Maybe the 2nd one should be solved 1stly. I have no idea...)

1. When I use `connection.someMethod();` SSLException occurs. (i.e `connection.getResponseCode();`)

The **Error** is :

`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x635cb550: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error`

2. What is alternative way of `List<NameValuePair> & BasicNameValuePair` ? Those are deprecated as well.

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar Could you please suggest any implementation example ?

Comment: https://github.com/smanikandan14/Volley-demo

Comment: https://github.com/johnjohndoe/Volley

Comment: As for using non-deprecated code, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33031158/4409409

Comment: http://square.github.io/retrofit/ is one of the best http client

Answer (score 1):

You can use following library for **HTTP requests-response**

- http://loopj.com/android-async-http/
- http://square.github.io/okhttp/
- http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

You can use **Google-Gson** for parsing JSON data

- https://github.com/google/gson

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use connect. Simply doing this:

```
 conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
 InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
 response = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(in, "UTF-8");
```

You will get your response.

Also, you can use ContentValues as a replacement for NameValuePair:

```
ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
initialValues.put("parameter", value);
```