# Android Login Registration System with PHP, MySQL with error 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.execute'

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, oracle

I have develop Android Login Registration System with PHP, MySQL. This is Simple questions but confuses me. i got many error as below log.

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.execute
>                                                                                                at com.chinatown.wangjian.chinatown_loginv10.Library.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:45)
>                                                                                                at com.chinatown.wangjian.chinatown_loginv10.Library.UserFunctions.loginUser(UserFunctions.java:42)
>                                                                                                at com.chinatown.wangjian.chinatown_loginv10.Login$ProcessLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:194)
>                                                                                                at com.chinatown.wangjian.chinatown_loginv10.Login$ProcessLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:170)
>   at com.chinatown.wangjian.chinatown_loginv10.Register$ProcessRegister.onPreExecute(Register.java:197)
>   at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
>   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
>                                                                                                 at com.chinatown.wangjian.chinatown_loginv10.Register$NetCheck.onPostExecute(Register.java:167)
>                                                                                                 at com.chinatown.wangjian.chinatown_loginv10.Register$NetCheck.onPostExecute(Register.java:119)                                                              >at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
>   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
>                                                                                               at com.chinatown.wangjian.chinatown_loginv10.Login$NetCheck.onPostExecute(Login.java:159)
>                                                                                               at com.chinatown.wangjian.chinatown_loginv10.Login$NetCheck.onPostExecute(Login.java:110)

there are part of my java code:

**JSONParser.java**

```
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();
```

**UserFunctions**

```
public JSONObject registerUser(String mobile, String email, String uname, String password){
    // Building Parameters
    List params = new ArrayList();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobile", mobile));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uname", uname));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(registerURL,params);
    return json;
}
```

**Register.java**

```
  private class ProcessRegister extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    String email,password,mobile,uname;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        inputUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        mobile = inputMobile.getText().toString();
        email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
        uname= inputUsername.getText().toString();
        password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
        pDialog.setTitle("正在链接服务器");
        pDialog.setMessage("注册中 ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

 protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {


        UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
        JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(mobile, email, uname, password);

        return json;


    }

 private class NetCheck extends AsyncTask<String,String,Boolean>
{
    private ProgressDialog nDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        nDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
        nDialog.setMessage("加载中..");
        nDialog.setTitle("正在检查网络");
        nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        nDialog.setCancelable(true);
        nDialog.show();
    }
```

I have refer the website try to fixed https://community.oracle.com/thread/2279492?start=0 and upgrade the httpcore-4.1.jar to latest version as below libs folder image. but it is not work for my project. I'm a newbie at this stuff so any help will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

[image: libs folder]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSONParser from androidhive tutorial, NoSuchMethodError in DefaultHttpClient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33030660/jsonparser-from-androidhive-tutorial-nosuchmethoderror-in-defaulthttpclient)

Answer (score 1):

The way you trying to communicate is obsolete. I mean many of class have been depricated, such as `DefaultHttpClient`, `BasicNameValuePair`,`HttpResponse` etc. Use [HTTPUrlConnection](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_network_connection.htm) for better performance.