# Download JSON in an AsyncTask [Android]

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

I'm trying to use an AsyncTask to return a list of objects it makes from reading a JSON response from a web API, but the code doesn't seem to be running properly.  I'm just wondering if anyone could give me a hand and point me to what I'm doing wrong.

**My AsyncTask class doInBackground() method:**

```
@Override
    protected List<DublinBusObject> doInBackground(String... params) {
        String liveUpdateUrl = params[0];
        List<DublinBusObject> dublinBusObjects = new ArrayList<>();
        try {

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(liveUpdateUrl);
            for (int x = 0; x < jsonObject.getJSONArray("stops").length(); x++) {

                this.busRoute = jsonObject.getString("bus_num");
                this.busDescription = jsonObject.getString("description");
                this.bueTime = jsonObject.getString("exected_dep");
                this.busStopId = jsonObject.getString("stop_id");

                DublinBusObject dublinBusObject = new DublinBusObject(busRoute, busDescription, bueTime, busStopId);
                dublinBusObjects.add(dublinBusObject);
            }

            if (android.os.Debug.isDebuggerConnected()) android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
            Log.e("TAG", jsonObject.keys().next().toString());
            Log.e("TAG", jsonObject.toString());

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return dublinBusObjects;
    }
```

**The JSON response it is trying to read:**

```
{  
   "stops":[  
      {  
         "aimed_dep":1437,
         "aimed_time":1437,
         "bus_num":"122",
         "congestion":"false",
         "description":"Ashington via City Centre",
         "direction":"Inbound",
         "exected_dep":1,
         "expected_time":1,
         "last_updated":1439,
         "stop_id":"00066",
         "timestamp":1439
      },
      {  
         "aimed_dep":27,
         "aimed_time":27,
         "bus_num":"122",
         "congestion":"false",
         "description":"Ashington via City Centre",
         "direction":"Inbound",
         "exected_dep":30,
         "expected_time":30,
         "last_updated":1439,
         "stop_id":"00066",
         "timestamp":1439
      },
      {  
         "aimed_dep":57,
         "aimed_time":57,
         "bus_num":"122",
         "congestion":"false",
         "description":"Ashington via City Centre",
         "direction":"Inbound",
         "exected_dep":57,
         "expected_time":57,
         "last_updated":1439,
         "stop_id":"00066",
         "timestamp":1439
      }
   ]
}
```

Sorry, I forgot to mention, this code:

```
DublinBusObject dublinBusObject = new DublinBusObject(busRoute,
                            busDescription, bueTime, busStopId);
dublinBusObjects.add(dublinBusObject);
```

doesn't run and add the new object to the ArrayList.

Comment: Whats the problem?

Comment: What is the value of `liveUpdateUrl`?

Comment: Its the JSON url I have in the post.

Comment: what about using debugger, plant breakpoint and check step-by-step?

Comment: The URL or the actual JSON String?

Comment: @DanielNugent its a URL, sorry it was edited out - the url is www.xelitexirish.com/homeFiles/live.json

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski when ever I try to use the debugger it either doesn't even notice it or will just skip over the method completly.

Comment: Did you call `.execute()` on the AsyncTask?

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes I have, and I know the task is running because if I breakpoint the "return" call the list is empty

Comment: I would strongly consider using Volley library instead of AsyncTask. The code to make a network request is significantly reduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually do a network operation in order to download the JSON response.  Then, you need to parse it correctly.

Here is code that would download the JSON response and parse it, you need to iterate over each JSONObject in the JSONArray:

```
//@Override
protected List<DublinBusObject> doInBackground(String... params) {
    String liveUpdateUrl = params[0];
    List<DublinBusObject> dublinBusObjects = new ArrayList<>();
    try {

        //Use JSONParser to download the JSON
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                liveUpdateUrl, "GET", new HashMap<String, String>());

        JSONArray jsonArray= jsonObject.getJSONArray("stops");
        for (int x = 0; x < jsonArray.length(); x++) {

            JSONObject jsonItem = jsonArray.getJSONObject(x);

            this.busRoute = jsonItem.getString("bus_num");
            this.busDescription = jsonItem.getString("description");
            this.bueTime = jsonItem.getString("exected_dep");
            this.busStopId = jsonItem.getString("stop_id");

            DublinBusObject dublinBusObject = new DublinBusObject(busRoute, busDescription, bueTime, busStopId);
            dublinBusObjects.add(dublinBusObject);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dublinBusObjects;
}
```

This uses this JSONParser class from [another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33031158/4409409):

```
import android.util.Log;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class JSONParser {

    String charset = "UTF-8";
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    DataOutputStream wr;
    StringBuilder result;
    URL urlObj;
    JSONObject jObj = null;
    StringBuilder sbParams;
    String paramsString;

    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                      HashMap<String, String> params) {

        sbParams = new StringBuilder();
        int i = 0;
        for (String key : params.keySet()) {
            try {
                if (i != 0){
                    sbParams.append("&");
                }
                sbParams.append(key).append("=")
                        .append(URLEncoder.encode(params.get(key), charset));

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            i++;
        }

        if (method.equals("POST")) {
            // request method is POST
            try {
                urlObj = new URL(url);

                conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();

                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);

                conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);

                conn.connect();

                paramsString = sbParams.toString();

                wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                wr.writeBytes(paramsString);
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else if(method.equals("GET")){
            // request method is GET

            if (sbParams.length() != 0) {
                url += "?" + sbParams.toString();
            }

            try {
                urlObj = new URL(url);

                conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();

                conn.setDoOutput(false);

                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);

                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);

                conn.connect();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        try {
            //Receive the response from the server
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            result = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }

            Log.d("JSON Parser", "result: " + result.toString());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        conn.disconnect();

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(result.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON Object
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

Comment: `I didn't realise you had to download it before hand` - that's kind of knocked me down :)