# Android POST with HTTP Url request

Tags: android, http, post, endpoint

I'm trying to use a POST command like this :

> http://123.456.78.9/Dev/SignIn?Username=email%40google.edu&Password=thePassword

in my Android app and I've looked at things like HTTPConnection but I'm still not sure what the best way to make a call like this where I'll need to include multiple key and values.

I'm trying this for now:

```
                URl url = new URL("http://123.456.78.9/Dev/SignIn?");     
                HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", emailText));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", passwordText));
                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(getQuery(params));
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();
```

Would this do the job? Also how do I go about getting the response if I was to use this method?

Comment: Take a look at android libraries which provides simple and powerful work with http connection. [volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) [okhttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) [retofit work with okhttp](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Comment: Looks like you're trying to do a GET request, not a POST request, as you have parameters in the query string....

Comment: Take a look at the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33030660/jsonparser-from-androidhive-tutorial-nosuchmethoderror-in-defaulthttpclient

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [Android Asynchronous Http Client library](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/):

```
final AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient=new AsyncHttpClient();
    //Add Parameter
    RequestParams requestParams=new RequestParams();
    requestParams.put("email", emailText);
    requestParams.put("Password", passwordText);

    //Chose one from two method in below

    //send with get method
    asyncHttpClient.get("http://123.456.78.9/Dev/SignIn", requestParams, new TextHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString) {
            System.out.println(responseString);
        }
    });

    //send with post method
    asyncHttpClient.post("http://123.456.78.9/Dev/SignIn", requestParams, new TextHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString) {
            System.out.println(responseString);
        }
    });
```

but you must add this library on your gradle

```
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
```