# How can i get JSON from php in android

Tags: java, android, json, web-services, http

i could not found codes. I want to this;

for example

```
JSONObject result = function("url",paramsArrayList);
txt.setText(result.getString["result1"]);
```

i want to use so basic, please help me, what should i use? Thanks...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33031158/4409409

Answer (score 0):

To send and receive data from php, you need to implement HTTP client in android side. I would strongly recommed you to use Retrofit, A type-safe HTTP client for Android and Java.

http://square.github.io/retrofit/

```
//delcare API interface
public interface TaskService {  
    @GET("/tasks")
    Call<List<Task>> getTasks();
}

//Asynchronous Request
TaskService taskService = ServiceGenerator.createService(TaskService.class);  
Call<List<Task>> call = taskService.getTasks();  
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Task>>() {  
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<Task>> call, Response<List<Task>> response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            // tasks available
        } else {
            // error response, no access to resource?
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<Task>> call, Throwable t) {
        // something went completely south (like no internet connection)
        Log.d("Error", t.getMessage());
    }
}
```