# Android Things: location over Wi-Fi

Tags: location, wifi, android-things

Hello it's possible to get location of Pico i.MX7 based on Android Things over Wi-Fi? When I run this code on phone everything works great, but when I run it on Pico, it seems that requestLocationUpdates doesn't update anything and the location is still null. I have permissions in Manifest too(both FINE and COARSE location). Thanks!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private LocationManager mLocationManager;
private String locationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;

private TextView lat;
private TextView lon;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lat);
    lon = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lon);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

        } else {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    2);
        }
    }

    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location location = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationProvider, 10, 0, mLocationListener);
    // Toast.makeText(this, "Start", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    showMyLocation(location);

    //Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SprinklerActivity.class);
    //startActivity(intent);
}

private void showMyLocation(Location l) {
    if (l == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        lat.setText("0");
        lon.setText("0");
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Latitude: " + l.getLatitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Longitude: " + l.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        lat.setText(l.getLatitude() + "");
        lon.setText(l.getLongitude() + "");
    }
}

private LocationListener mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        showMyLocation(location);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }
};
```

Comment: Do you have GPS turned on on the phone?

Comment: @Onik no, only wifi

Comment: Is `Pico` and your phone are on the same WiFi network?

Comment: Yes they are. I even tried to connect Pico with cable but it still doesn't work

Comment: I recieve first null in LastKnownLocation and new location updates are not recieved. Yes, I tried to reinstall it too

Comment: Are you using the Google Play Services location provider or one built into the OS? The built-in version may only use GPS whereas Play Services will use several sensors

Comment: @Nick Felker, he uses built-in API. Yuro8, try with [FusedLocationProviderClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient)

Comment: I tried it even with FusedLocaton but still the same problem :(

Comment: Yes it's installed.I compile these two: 
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:11.6.0'

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is no implementation for automatically update location in Android Things (even for `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER`), but anyway, if you have Internet access, you can use [Google Maps Geolocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro) requests like:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

with information about target [WiFi access point](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro#wifi_access_point_object) in request, and if target WiFi access point is in Google database your got [response JSON](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro#responses) with Lat/Lon and accuracy. For more precisely results you should use [GPS module](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00M7VCHZQ), connected via, for example, UART. [Here](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/drivers/gps.html) is the official description of using GPS modules on Android Things, and [here](https://github.com/androidthings/contrib-drivers/tree/master/gps) - the source code of user mode driver. Moreover, if you use GPS module with  [`GpsDriver`](https://developer.android.com/things/reference/com/google/android/things/userdriver/GpsDriver.html) you can send the location update to the framework (via [`.reportLocation()`](https://developer.android.com/things/reference/com/google/android/things/userdriver/GpsDriver.html#reportLocation(android.location.Location)) method) and your question code should works.

Comment: I'm fine with precision about +-1km, even more, so wifi should be enough. It's pity that it doesn't update. This solution looks so complicated :( but I try to give it a shot.

Comment: @Yuro8 It's not so complicated, as it seems at first look. There are many [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29466338/6950238) and [tutorials](https://www.studytutorial.in/android-httpurlconnection-post-and-get-request-tutorial).

Comment: Yeah, but now I'm reading that it's impossible to get the mac address of device from Android 6.0 and higher. Oh god, the android things is so ragged

Comment: @Yuro8 Try to add fake address like "01:23:45:67:89:AB". Or at first get WiFi MAC address from UI (Settings->etc.)

Comment: I think the request is good but it still return 400 - JSON not valid :(
`
{"cellTowers":
 [{"cellId":"",
"locationAreaCode":"",
"mobileCountryCode":"",
"mobileNetworkCode":""}],
"wifiAccessPoints":[ {
"macAddress":"01:23:45:67:89:AB"},{"macAddress":"11:23:45:67:89:AB"}]}
`

Comment: @Yuro8 Send empty `cellTowers` array, or even not add that tag instead of send empty ("") fields. And there are strange symbols after 67 in second mac address. At first, try to send JSON from [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro#request_body): `{
  "considerIp": "false",
  "wifiAccessPoints": [
    {
        "macAddress": "00:25:9c:cf:1c:ac",
        "signalStrength": -43,
        "signalToNoiseRatio": 0
    },
    {
        "macAddress": "00:25:9c:cf:1c:ad",
        "signalStrength": -55,
        "signalToNoiseRatio": 0
    }
  ]
}`