# How to retrieve data from connection and save to 'shared preference'?

Tags: android

Like the title says, I am trying to retrieve data from a connection and save the data (which is just some values) to the [shared preference](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage#pref).

The connection is working if I test and just run with [main()](https://www.journaldev.com/12552/public-static-void-main-string-args-java-main-method) method but it doesn't work within the app if I call the code with the onCreate() event. It won't save the data and it will always be null.

```java
sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

try {
    String link = "...";
    URL url = new URL(link);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    if (responseCode == 200) {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        (conn.getInputStream())));
        String output, totalString = "";
        while ((output = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            totalString += output;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, totalString);

        com.google.gson.JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonParser().parse(totalString)
                        .getAsJsonObject();

        String time = jsonObject.getAsJsonObject("data").getAsJsonObject("timings")
                        .get("Fajr").getAsString();
        Log.d(TAG, "Fajr: " + time);

        editor.putString("key_fajr", time);
        editor.apply();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
}
```

The code I use to retrieve data:

```java
sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
String value = sharedPref.getString("key_fajr", null);
```

Exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to api.aladhan.com not permitted
```

I expect it will get the data from the connection and save it in shared preference within the app.

Comment: Have you declared the INTERNET permission in your manifest ?

Comment: I see you have logs. What is the problem here? Is the connection not working or is the value not saved in SharedPreferences?

Comment: does your `Log.d(TAG, "Fajr: " + time);` show anything? Also... when are you reading from the sharedPref?

Comment: I suggest to use `getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(TAG, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` and `commit();` instead of `apply();`

Comment: @Ezio yes i did!

Comment: @YoavGibri I think the connection is not working when call using onCreate() :(

Comment: @remedy. No :( I also can't find the log, I think it is not executed

Comment: @Raskilas I have tried but it is still the same :(

Comment: @hadif First, you can see the log in the LogCat section in the bottom of Android Studio. Can you add the log (set on Debug) to your question? Second, does the app crashes?

Comment: Try reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29466338/6519248) and using the code from there, it is very similar you yours.

Comment: @YoavGibri thanks that is a bit helpful, now i found that the problem is it doesnt go to the if statement which is the connection response.. then it just direct to the catch statement. This is my code with the log.d https://pastebin.com/eBWuSX6b

Comment: @YoavGibri I tried to follow the answer but it always throw the exception.. :(

Comment: Founded error: java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to api.aladhan.com not permitted

Comment: @YoavGibri nvm fix it, the only problem is that on Android 9 cleartext support is disabled by default, thats the problem came from... I really appreciate your help sir! ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I have found the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50834600/9260075), I just write it here for some other future programmer use.

The problem is that I'm in Android 9 which is...

> Starting with Android 9 (API level 28), cleartext support is disabled by default.

That's why in my case the exception occurs as follows:

```
java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to url not permitted
```

Plus, there's nothing to do with Shared Preferences. Everything is working as it supposed to be.

#### Solutions

Just add this line in AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        ...
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Create editor and preferences**

```
private var preferences: SharedPreferences? = null
private var editor: SharedPreferences.Editor? = null
```

**Init editor and preferences**

```
preferences = activity!!.getSharedPreferences("key_fajr", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
//In fragment
//preferences = getActivity()!!.getSharedPreferences("key_fajr",     Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
editor = preferences!!.edit()
```

**Save Data**

```
editor!!.putString("email", mEtEmail!!.text.toString())
editor!!.commit()
```

**Load Data**

```
preferences!!.getString("email", "")
```